# Dataframe formation from another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like below -

```
ID  Description  Question    Answer
 1     abc        Q1          A1
 1     abc        Q2          A2
 2     xyz        Q1          Ans1

....
```

There are 5 unique question in the column `Question`. For each description in `Description` column, the `Answer` column has the answer for the question in `Question` column.

I want to convert it to a `df` like this -

```
ID   Description  Q1  Q2  Q3`
1      abc         A1  A2  A3
...
```

such that there is only one row corresponding to each `ID` and the 5 questions will be 5 columns containing answers.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: (1) is this a pandas DataFrame object? (2) the input doesn't map to the output. For example, where are `description=xyz` and `Answer=Ans1` in the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sample pandas DataFrame - `sample_df` - as below:

```
   ID Description Question Answer
0   1         abc       Q1     A1
1   1         abc       Q2     A2
2   1         abc       Q3     A2
3   2         xyz       Q1     A1
4   2         xyz       Q2     A1
5   2         xyz       Q3     A2
```

You can pivot it as below:

```
output_df = sample_df.pivot_table(
    index=['ID', 'Description'],
    columns=['Question'],
    values=['Answer'],
    aggfunc='first'
)
```

And it will become:

```
               Answer        
Question           Q1  Q2  Q3
ID Description               
1  abc             A1  A2  A2
2  xyz             A1  A1  A2
```

where the columns ID and Description will be treated as indexes for the output DataFrame.